# Calculate the space traveled by a mobile

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Calculate the distance that the mobile traveled,if the initial velocity is 5m/s (meters per seconds ) ,the acceleration is constant and it's 2m/s^2(meters per (seconds)^2) ,and the time it's 1 hour.
Initial velocity =5m/s
Acceleration =2m/s
Time = 1 hour (60 minutes)
Distance =?

Why is this question relevant: I'm new into mechanical physics and
What I tried exactly: the law of space is :(d.t)(distance ) x=xo+v.o(initial speed)*t+a*t^2/2  ,a=delta v /delta t ,so v=1,44 m/s ,v=speed ,t=time ,a=acceleration, then I found xo ,v^2=v.o+2*a*x ,I calculate x ,and it's =13,8 .Then I just applied the equation (d.t)=distance= xo+v.o*t+a*t^2=

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Initial velocity is 5 $ms^{-1}$ and acceleration is constant 2 $ms^{-2}$ then what is the problem in calculating distance traveled in 1 hour. It's so easy. If you are having any conceptual problem be clear about that as it is so hard to understand what you have written.

Comment: @Community,I'm asking for the distance

Comment: @HarjotDhillon,the initial velocity is 5m/s and the acceleration is 2m/s

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have the right formula - the distance travelled in time $t$ with initial velocity $v$ and constant acceleration $a$ is

$\displaystyle x(t) = vt + \frac 1 2 at^2$

and you know that $v=5$ m/s, $a=2$ m/s^2 and $t=3600$ seconds.

You must have made a mistake in your arithmetic.

Comment: ,yeah ,thank you  a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I don't understand all of your equations out of context. However, the key here is to consider the position function $x(t)$ as a function of time. Then, basic calculus gives us that the velocity function is $x'(t)$ and the acceleration function is $x''(t)$. In this language, your problem can be restated as follows:

> Find $x(3600)$, given that $x'(0)=5$ and $x''(t)=2$.

You can also assume $x(0)=0$, since this just means that we label the mobile's starting position "$0$". If you're not used to solving differential equations, I think you should still be able to tackle the one above - it's a relatively simple one, which relies only on basic integration. One hint is that your solution will be a quadratic equation, of the form $x(t)=At^2+Bt+C$ for some constants $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Let me know if you want any more guidance!

Comment: ,the equation that I used are kinematics equation ( equations of motion ),the last equation that you wrote is the galileo galilei law of velocity that I used in my solving

Comment: I'm not used to differential equation ,but I understand what you are saying